# Serialize own interface as ObjectId field?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have an interface for a database id (this is due to an architectural boundary). 
The interface only exposes a string property publically in order to avoid dependency on the driver library itself (i.e. MongoDB.xxx).

```
public interface IDatabaseId
{
    string Id { get; set; }
}
```

I implemented this contract in my database wrapper library using MongoDB's ObjectId (using ObjectId.GenerateNewId() internally and passing the stringified version to the public Id field).

In one of my business classes I have such an ID field which I would like to be serialized as an ObjectID in an according collection's document.

```
[BsonId(Order = 0)]
public IDatabaseId Id { get; set; }
```

I tried to use a custom serializer where I take the string Id property and de/serialize it from/as an ObjectID. This works, however in my mongo db collection the _id field is NOT directly an ObjectId field but an Object with an embedded _id field.

My question is, how can I serialize my custom object as an ObjectId field directly?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is not to write a document start in the serializer but directly write the object id value.